# Selenium "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZxpv5l5JvY&feature=share&list=PLrM2ELpRbbu5cWJbRuzpAr6SR40Gb0QHU&index=10

Then instead of typing my own code I copy/pasted the code given by selenium IDE export function (I recorded my actions first) into the class file.

But I get all these errors, unknown symbols, why is that, isn't maven supposed to resolve them ? I did eveything they say in the tutorial...

[image: Errors in the code]

https://picload.org/image/cglicod/selnium.jpg

What is going on, all I want is to get this IDE exported code to work.

Comment: where do you see this message in your screenshot. I only see the message `class ... is public ...`

Comment: well every time i hover my mouse on a red word it says that, i will reupload the picture

Comment: maven doesn't resolv this, because that is a java standard class. Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Try to reopen the IDE ... then try clean & refresh

Comment: I tried to relaunch the IDE but it didn't help. How do I clean the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this project references an **non existing JDK/JRE**.
Check which JDK/JRE is configured (in project settings) and check if it really exists.

Comment: I can't find it where is the JDK/JRE in project settings ? Can't find any path prompt under the compiler option.

Comment: Ok I checked the sdk is :  C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_20, it is where I installed, the file exists.

Comment: i see in your screenshot that your filename differs from its containing java class-(name) (check case sensitivity! Classes always begin with Uppercase Letter!) maybe this can be a problem in "your" environment.

Comment: well you were right on both count, first I think there was some kind of IDE glitch, I re-entered the adress for JDK and it looked like it refresh few things and the red words were no more. Then for the uppercase it was a problem I ran into afterwards too. So thank you for your help !